# Selecting optimal PayPal API

Tags: paypal

I've been given a task to integrate PayPal API to an already existing website, where buyer details should be taken out from the existing user database and all front-end design should be custom - created as part of whole system design.

I basically need to select PayPal API that will allow me to simply authorize and invoke credit card charge for selected amount of cache based on user details and credit card information.

Which of the PayPal API's is designed for this?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use [Payments Pro](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/development-and-integration-guides#wpp) for that.